# Mediator deadlock on async await within background worker - how to detect thread calling itself

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library, mediator

I have a mediator which I have recently needed to synchronize one at a time message dispatch on a background thread but it is locking, demonstrated below.

I post a command to a queue and return a task from a TaskCompletionSource:

```
public Task<object> Send(object command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var item = new CommandItem() { Command = request, Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(), Ct = cancellationToken };            
    this.queue.Writer.WriteAsync(item); // just write and immediatly return the tcs
    return item.Tcs.Task;
}
```

It then is picked up from the background worker, and handler created:

```
var item = await this.queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);
// work out command  type snipped
var command = item.Command as LockMeGoodCommand;
var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler();
var result = await handler.Handle(command, item.Ct);
item.Tcs.SetResult(result);
```

It is then handled, with the below locking up when the command handler is send to within the command handler (when using a background thread, but within thread it is OK):

```
public async Task<int> Handle(LockMeGoodCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   Console.WriteLine(command.GetType().Name);

   // this would get the result but will lock forever when using background worker bus implementation
   var otherResult = await this.commandBus.Send(new BoringCommand(), cancellationToken);

   // perform some action based on the result - but we never get here
   Console.WriteLine("otherResult is " + otherResult);

   return 3;
}
```

** Question and potential fix **

**I believe we can avoid a deadlock by detecting if the background thread is posting to it itself from within its thread (via the command handler which then calls Send() to post a new command), and if so it should not use any thread mechanics (post to the command queue or TaskCompletionSource) and should instead simply handle the task directly.**

I have tried to detect the thread but it is not working, so i set the manual flag isSameThread to true within my handler above `var otherResult = await this.commandBus.Send(new BoringCommand(), cancellationToken, true)` and **I can confirm it works and the deadlock is avoided**.

Any caveats in this fix? How would one detect if the background thread is requesting to send a command (how can a thread detect itself) and how would one finish off the below code (from `DispatchOnBackgroundThread.Send()` to include this self-calling detection (so I can do away with the isSameThread flag)?

It would seem this is more involved as each await will give a different thread ID.

```
// in thread start we set the thread id of the background thread
this.workerThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

public Task<object> Send(object command, CancellationToken cancellationToken, bool isSameThread = false)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"this.workerThreadId: {this.workerThreadId}, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

    // below doesnt work gives different numbers so i use flag instead
    // this.workerThreadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
    if (isSameThread == true)
    {
        if (command is BoringCommand boringCommand)
        {
            var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
            return handler.Handle(boringCommand, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => (object)t);

        }
        else if (command is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
        {
            var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this);
            return handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t => (object)t);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("unknown");
    }
    else
    {
        var item = new CommandItem() { Command = command, Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(), Ct = cancellationToken };
        this.queue.Writer.WriteAsync(item); // just write and immediatly return the cts
        return item.Tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

** Code demonstrating issue **

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestDeadlock
{
    class BoringCommand { }
    class LockMeGoodCommand { }    

    class BoringCommandHandler
    {
        public Task<int> Handle(BoringCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(command.GetType().Name);         
            return Task.FromResult(1);
        }
    }
    class LockMeGoodCommandHandler
    {
        private readonly DispatchOnBackgroundThread commandBus;

        public LockMeGoodCommandHandler(DispatchOnBackgroundThread commandBus) => this.commandBus = commandBus;

        public async Task<int> Handle(LockMeGoodCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(command.GetType().Name);

            // this locks forever
            var otherResult = await this.commandBus.Send(new BoringCommand(), cancellationToken);
            Console.WriteLine("otherResult is " + otherResult);
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public class DispatchOnBackgroundThread
    {
        private readonly Channel<CommandItem> queue = Channel.CreateUnbounded<CommandItem>();
        private Task worker = null;

        class CommandItem
        {
            public object Command { get; set; }
            public CancellationToken Ct { get; set; }
            public TaskCompletionSource<object> Tcs { get; set; }
        }

        public Task<object> Send(object command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var item = new CommandItem()
            { Command = command, Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(), Ct = cancellationToken };            
            this.queue.Writer.WriteAsync(item); // just write and immediatly return the tcs
            return item.Tcs.Task;
        }

        public void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            this.worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                try
                {                    
                    while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                    {
                        var item = await this.queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

                        // simplified DI container magic to static invocation
                        if (item.Command is BoringCommand boringCommand)
                        {
                            var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
                            var result = await handler.Handle(boringCommand, item.Ct);
                            item.Tcs.SetResult(result);
                        }
                        if (item.Command is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
                        {
                            var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this);
                            var result = await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, item.Ct);
                            item.Tcs.SetResult(result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
            },
            TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
            .Unwrap();
        }

        public async Task StopAsync()
        {
            this.queue.Writer.Complete();
            await this.worker;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var threadStrategy = new DispatchOnBackgroundThread();
            threadStrategy.Start(cts.Token);

            var result1 = await threadStrategy.Send(new BoringCommand(), cts.Token);
            var result2 = await threadStrategy.Send(new LockMeGoodCommand(), cts.Token);

            cts.Cancel();
            await threadStrategy.StopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

** Simple non-threaded mediator implementation that works without locking **

```
public class DispatchInCallingThread
{
    public async Task<object> Send(object request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // simplified DI container magic to static invocation
        if (request is BoringCommand boringCommand)
        {
            var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
            return await handler.Handle(boringCommand, cancellationToken);
        }
        else if (request is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
        {
            var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this);
            return await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("unknown");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's way too much code. It is practically certain that only a fraction of the code you posted is actually involved in the deadlock. Please fix. In the meantime: frankly, the chances that you've discovered some deadlock scenario not already adequately addressed by the many existing questions on SO is slim to none. You've got a thread that should be doing work, another thread that is waiting for it to do work, and each thread is waiting on each other. ...

Comment: ... All you really need is to break in the debugger and see where each thread is blocked. Fixing will be just like fixing any deadlock: don't create mutual lock dependencies (avoid taking multiple locks if possible, if not then make sure you always take all locks in the same order regardless of thread).

Comment: Hi Peter thank you for the time. I have included both a summary of the locking session and code example should anyone be kind enough to run it. I agree it is long (ish) but have included the non-threaded version (which works). I am not using locks. I have looked in detail on SO before posting, but I admit I am stuck

Comment: _"I am not using locks."_ -- not explicitly, but there are implicit locks involved in the thread sync required to support your use of `await` and `TaskCompletionSource`. For example, two methods which are awaiting on each other's completion will neither complete. Don't take "lock" so literally here. In any case, the inclusion of working code is pointless and only distracts from the question, and even the broken code is likely not **minimal** to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have cleaned the question to make clearer thanks for pointers/patience - I believe a deadlock can be avoided entirely by detecting new command posts that are being done within a handler, and if so handle directly instead of posting a command to the queue with new TaskCompletionSource etc - I would handle the reenterant/nested command within the same background thread (just like the single  threaded mediator). I have updated the question to ask, assuming this is the correct fix, how one would detect that we are the background thread that is posting the command request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Stephen for the answer and Peter for the comments, it indeed blindingly clear when stated thank you,

> There is one code loop (not a specific thread; see below) that is
>   responsible for processing the queue. As it processes each command, it
>   awaits that command's handler.
>
> There is a command handler that awaits another command to be handled.
>   However, this cannot work because no further commands will be
>   processed; the code loop will not dequeue the next command until this
>   one completes.

With the above in mind I have found a way to handle without any threading hacks (detecting stack/re-entrance depth etc) or schedulers.

In the example below I "inject" into the handler not the looping calling class, but a different type of command handler dispatcher which does not do any queuing, it instead processes directly within the thread.

The below is called from within the thread loop, then there is no inter-dependency:

```
public class DispatchInCallingThread: ICommandBus
{
    public async Task<object> Send(object request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // simplified DI container magic to static invocation
        if (request is BoringCommand boringCommand)
        {
            var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
            return await handler.Handle(boringCommand, cancellationToken);
        }
        else if (request is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
        {
            var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this);
            return await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, cancellationToken);
        }
        else
            throw new Exception("cough furball");
    }

    public void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }

    public Task StopAsync() { return Task.CompletedTask; }
}
```

And within the background thread, this is the injection into the instantiated command handler:

```
else if (item.Command is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
{
    var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this.dispatchInCallingThread);
    var result = await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, item.Ct);
    item.Tcs.SetResult(result);
}
```

Now the code runs forever (will need to implement proper shutdown logic for cancellation token source being set):

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestDeadlock
{
    class BoringCommand { }
    class LockMeGoodCommand { }    

    class BoringCommandHandler
    {
        public Task<int> Handle(BoringCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(command.GetType().Name);         
            return Task.FromResult(1);
        }
    }

    class LockMeGoodCommandHandler
    {
        private readonly ICommandBus commandBus;

        public LockMeGoodCommandHandler(ICommandBus commandBus) => this.commandBus = commandBus;

        public async Task<int> Handle(LockMeGoodCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {            
            Console.WriteLine(command.GetType().Name);
            var otherResult =  await this.commandBus.Send(new BoringCommand(), cancellationToken);
            var otherResult2 = await this.commandBus.Send(new BoringCommand(), cancellationToken);
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public interface ICommandBus
    {
        Task<object> Send(object request, CancellationToken cancellationToken);
        void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
        Task StopAsync();
    }

    public class DispatchOnBackgroundThread : ICommandBus
    {
        private readonly Channel<CommandItem> queue = Channel.CreateUnbounded<CommandItem>();
        private Task worker = null;
        private readonly DispatchInCallingThread dispatchInCallingThread = new DispatchInCallingThread();

        class CommandItem
        {
            public object Command { get; set; }
            public CancellationToken Ct { get; set; }
            public TaskCompletionSource<object> Tcs { get; set; }
        }

        public Task<object> Send(object command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var item = new CommandItem() { Command = command, Tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(), Ct = cancellationToken };
            this.queue.Writer.WriteAsync(item, cancellationToken); // just write and immediatly return the cts
            return item.Tcs.Task;            
        }

        public void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var scheduler = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();

            this.worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                CommandItem item = null;
                try
                {                
                    while (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                    {
                        item = await this.queue.Reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken);

                        // simplified DI container magic to static invocation
                        if (item.Command is BoringCommand boringCommand)
                        {
                            var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
                            var result = handler.Handle(boringCommand, item.Ct);
                            item.Tcs.SetResult(result);

                        }
                        else if (item.Command is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
                        {
                            var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this.dispatchInCallingThread);
                            var result = await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, item.Ct);
                            item.Tcs.SetResult(result);
                        }
                        else
                            throw new Exception("unknown");
                    }
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                        item.Tcs.SetCanceled();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("exit background thread");
            })
            .Unwrap();  

        }

        public async Task StopAsync()
        {
            this.queue.Writer.Complete();
            await this.worker;
        }
    }

    public class DispatchInCallingThread: ICommandBus
    {
        public async Task<object> Send(object request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // simplified DI container magic to static invocation
            if (request is BoringCommand boringCommand)
            {
                var handler = new BoringCommandHandler();
                return await handler.Handle(boringCommand, cancellationToken);
            }
            else if (request is LockMeGoodCommand lockMeGoodCommand)
            {
                var handler = new LockMeGoodCommandHandler(this);
                return await handler.Handle(lockMeGoodCommand, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("unknown");
        }

        public void Start(CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }
        public Task StopAsync() { return Task.CompletedTask; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await TestDispatchOnBackgroundThread();
        }

        static async Task TestDispatchOnBackgroundThread()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate {
                Console.WriteLine("setting cts.Cancel()");
                cts.Cancel();
            };

            var threadStrategy = new DispatchOnBackgroundThread();
            threadStrategy.Start(cts.Token);

            while (cts.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***************** sending new batch ****************");                
                var result1 = await threadStrategy.Send(new BoringCommand(), cts.Token);
                var result3 = await threadStrategy.Send(new LockMeGoodCommand(), cts.Token);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            await threadStrategy.StopAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

For further info, the actual implementation with dependency injection is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791817/915839 which was able to dynamically switch to in-thread dispatch within the worker thread

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the deadlock is rather simple:

- There is one code loop (not a specific thread; see below) that is responsible for processing the queue. As it processes each command, it `await`s that command's handler.
- There is a command handler that `await`s another command *to be handled*. However, this cannot work because no further commands will be processed; the code loop will not dequeue the next command until this one completes.

Put another way, it is not logically possible for one command to execute another command if commands can only be executed one at a time.

There's a few possible approaches to solving this problem. I do *not* recommend the "re-entrant" approach; reentrancy is the cause of many subtle logic bugs. The approaches I would recommend are one of:

1. Change the `Send` semantics so that they're a "queue" semantic. This means it's not possible to get command results; results would have to be sent as a message through some mediator.
2. Have the code loop not `await` the command handler, allowing it to loop back and pick up the next command. This means it doesn't "synchronize one at a time" any more.
3. Redefine "synchronize one at a time" to mean "one at a time but if it's `await`ing then it doesn't count as one". In that case, you can probably use something like `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` or `Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext` to run the method chunks one at a time.

Side note: `LongRunning` doesn't do what you think it's doing. [`StartNew` is not `async`-aware](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), so the `LongRunning` flag only applies to the code up to the first `await`; after that, the code in that lambda will run on arbitrary thread pool threads (without `LongRunning` set). Replacing `StartNew` with `Task.Run` will make the code more clear.

Comment: Stephen thank you for the answer and pointers, after your comments I realised my design was flawed. Using dependency injection I ensured the in-calling-thread dispatcher (no queue straight through) implementation was passed to any handler (if requested in constructor) so that if the handler did post it would bypass the queue/worker logic and simply handle the await inline within the calling thread of the worker. Your comments were pivotal to this review and helped avoid a re-enterant approach with what turned out to be quite succinct flow