# Can I change the service configuration for a child scope?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection

I would like to create a new DI scope changing a service registration, I have several use cases where I need it, for example a have two implementations for `ICurrentPrincipalAccessor`, `ThreadPrincipalAccessor` and `HttpContextPrincipalAccessor`, I used to use `ThreadPrincipalAccesor` in console and `HttpContextPrincipalAccesor` for ASP.NET. In library classes I inject `ICurrentPrincipalAccesor`, I didn't have problems until I have needed to access to principal from a hosted service in a ASP.NET application.

Due it's a ASP.NET application I have registered:

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICurrentPrincipalAccessor, HttpContextPrincipalAccesor>();
```

Then in a hosted service I create a child scope:

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope()) 
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyGreatServiceWhatDoSomethingWithPrincipal>();
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

`MyGreatServiceWhatDoSomethingWithPrincipal` have a `ICurrentPrincipalAccessor` dependency and `HttpContextPrincipalAccesor` is injected but in this case, calling from hosted service, I would like to inject `ThreadPrincipalAccessor`, I would like to do somethink like:

```cs
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope(collectionService => {
        // Define here the new scope service configurations
        collectionService.AddTransient<ICurrentPrincipalAccessor, ThreadPrincipalAccesor>();
    })) 
{
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyGreatServiceWhatDoSomethingWithPrincipal>();
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

Yes, I could access to `HttpContext.User` and if it's null access to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, ok! but there are more use cases where I would like change de service configuration for a child scope.

Can you help me?

By the other hand, I'm using Autofac as IoC container, perhaps I can do something specific with Autofac.

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61791817/264697). A similar solution would work in your case, or a variation where you inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into the `SwitchableBus` (which would be `CurrentPrincipalAccessorProxy`).

Answer (score 2):

Well, the last note in my own question open a new way on my head.

I have been viewing the [`ServiceProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/tree/master/src/DI) code and I didn't see a posibility of do it. However I have been searching in the [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html#adding-registrations-to-a-lifetime-scope) and I understood it's possible.

I have create my own service scope factory:

```cs
public interface ISinaiServiceScopeFactory
{
    IServiceScope CreateScope(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices);
}
public class SinaiServiceScopeFactory : ISinaiServiceScopeFactory
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _lifetimeScope;

    public SinaiServiceScopeFactory(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
    {
        _lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
    }
    public IServiceScope CreateScope(Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
    {
        var sc = new SinaiServiceCollection();
        configureServices.Invoke(sc);

        var scope = this._lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(container =>
        {
            container.Populate(sc);
        });
        return new AutofacServiceScope(scope); // That is internal in Autofac, I have created a copy :P
    }
}
```

> *<sub>AutofacServiceScope [sourcecode](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacServiceScope.cs)</sub>*

And an extension method for service provider:

```cs
public static class SinaiServiceProviderExtensions
{
    public static IServiceScope CreateScope(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        Action<IServiceCollection> configureServices)
    {
        var serviceScopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetService<ISinaiServiceScopeFactory>();
        return serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope(configureServices);
    }
}
```

The tests works fine:

```cs
public class SinaiServiceScopeFactoryTests
{
    interface I1 {}
    class C1 : I1 {}
    class C2 : I1 {}

    [Fact]
    public void Should_Override_Services_On_New_Scope()
    {
        var sc = new SinaiServiceCollection();
        sc.AddTransient<I1, C1>();
        sc.AddTransient<ISinaiServiceScopeFactory, SinaiServiceScopeFactory>();

        var spf = new AutofacServiceProviderFactory();
        var builder = spf.CreateBuilder(sc);
        var sp = spf.CreateServiceProvider(builder);

        var service1 = sp.GetService<I1>();

        using (var scope = sp.CreateScope(sc => sc.AddTransient<I1, C2>()))
        {
            var service2 = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<I1>();

            Assert.Equal(typeof(C1), service1.GetType());
            Assert.Equal(typeof(C2), service2.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```